# Como passar parâmetros através do Link no React?

Tags: react

Como faço para passar um parâmetro usando o Link?

No caso eu quero passar dentro do Link o ID do meu produto para eu recuperar esse valor no meu outro componente.

Porém no `to=""` eu não consigo passar o valor em JSX.

No caso eu queria que ficasse assim:

```
<Link className="btn btn-warning" to="/editalivro/:{lista.id}">Editar</Link>
```

Tentei usando crase, porém não funciona o `to` só aceita "".

Como posso passar esse valor via param?

Answer (score 1):

Bastou adicionar {} chaves no to e concatenar que resolveu.

```
<Link className="btn btn-warning" to={"/editalivro/" + lista.id}>Editar</Link>
```